# Is it difficult to be fully funded for PhD in STEM field in US?

Tags: phd, funding, united-states, engineering, stem

I have reached out to some professors for my research interest.  I am wondering whether it is difficult to be fully funded for my PhD program in civil engineering. 
Is it appropriate to ask the professors whether I will be fully funded for my PhD?

Comment: TL;DR the vast majority of engineering PhDs in the US are funded. See [actual numbers for "primary source of support" here](https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsf16300/data/tab35.pdf).

Comment: Furthermore, you  _should_ be fully funded.

Comment: Most lab-heavy degrees can fully fund you even if it takes you 8+ years to get a Ph.D.; you pay for yourself in lab work.  Engineering tends to need lots of TAs for labs/classes, and is well-funded to boot.  In mathematics some schools will not have any funding to offer until you're fully vested in the Ph.D. program (passed the written and oral quals.), and even then you may still only get funded through your advisor's grants (so if they're short, you're out of luck).  UCLA had this "problem" when I was applying, for example.  Others can fully fund you for at least 4 years, possibly more.

Comment: "Fully-funded" means they pay you and you don't do any work for them?  Or would you include situations where you have to do clerical work/instructional work/laboratory work in return for the money?

Comment: I'm in your field, it is not very hard if you have a good application/contacts and work with with a decent professor (R1, R2)

Comment: If by "fully funded" you mean a research assistantship -- those are the plum positions and you should not count on getting this.  If you mean a teaching assistantship -- this is very doable, and yes, you should definitely ask.  Count on working 20 hours a week.  The core of your work would probably be grading homework, which can be quite tedious, hence, this work is given to the grad students to do.

Comment: I am hoping to work with a professor who has won some grants. I am hearing that it is wrong to do PhD in STEm field without being fully funded (paying nothing out of your pocket).  Hope this becomes true for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is appropriate to ask, both for the program and the individual professors. Hopefully you ask other important and research-related questions at the same time, but funding is not a taboo topic for a prospective student, and it should be one of the keys to your decision if you are accepted to multiple programs.

Many programs (in STEM in general, can't speak to civil engineering in particular) offer fully-funded programs (tuition+a stipend) for PhDs (less often for masters), but there may be limits (for example you may be guaranteed for only 5-6 years, and if it takes longer you might still get funding just not guaranteed), and you almost certainly won't be free to do whatever you want: you may be required to teach ("TA") whether you want to or not, you may be required to join a lab that has funding available ("RA"), even if that lab was not your first choice otherwise, or you might have to do other work for another lab/group that isn't directly related to your research (as an RA or PA). Fellowships or traineeships are directly funding YOU and are the best source of funding but are often competitive and may cover only a short period of time.

"Fully funded" could include ANY combination of the above, so you should ask questions about the types of funding and not just a guarantee. Current students are also a great resource.

Comment: I met up with my potential professor that I want to work for and he mentioned that it will be fully funded with any of the combinations you mentioned. TA, RA or both. It is a great news though. Thank you and everyone else for helpful comments